# Multilingual PHP Application w/ Variables in Content

Tags: php

Long-time lurker, first time poster (please go easy on me).

Background:
I have written a fairly large, complex internal (behind corporate firewall) application for a financial institution. We are now looking at deploying to offices around the world, which will require the content to be translated.

Specific problem:
Much of the content has variables in the content and this is fairly fundamental to the application.

Solutions I have explored:

1.) Content stored in a database - Easy to manage, easy to search, and easy to apply a single content block to multiple pages/use. Cannot [easily] store variables in the content.

2.) Variables in prepared SQL statements - Unfortunately the prepared variables can only be in the WHERE portion of the query by the looks of it. I was hoping to have "Some content :prepared_variable" stored in the DB and handle it that way but no luck there.

3.) Content in XML/JSON/.ini - Same issues as a database, variables don't get parsed/populated.

4.) eval() - Everyone says it's evil. Is this maybe a case where it can or has to be used? I could create a seperate .sqlite database that the application never writes to for content storage thereby reducing the potential for executing random code. In reality if someone get's in and modifies our DB we have bigger problems although I do see the risk and am very hesitant to go this route. I am also concerned that if I go this route the application may not pass any potential audit.

I can think of a few overly complicated solutions but prefer not to utilize them:

1.) Processing all logic then loading language from template files.

2.) Concatenating language on either end of variables when necessary.

3.) Load content from a DB and run str_replace to insert variables.

My specific question, has anyone dealt with multilingual applications? How did you handle variables in content? Is there any option(s) I have missed?

Comment: Are you trying to change the variable names in the code itself or the text output to the page by the variable?

Comment: "Much of the content has variables within the content and this is fairly fundamental to the application. " <- what does this even mean. I try rewording it for you but still can't figure it out.

Comment: If by #1 under *"prefer not to use them"* you're referring to AJAX. I believe for multilingual support that is your best option. Using AJAX you can create many language `XML` files then provide a method in your back-end allowing the user to select their language of preference. That selection is stored in the database so when the user returns their selected language file is used to populate content on the page.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much text is involved, how many languages you need to support, whether localization is an issue and what kind of budget you have.  The fastest solution may be to create separate instances for each language, which will be a maintenance nightmare.

If there isn't too much code, I suggest you consider choosing a framework with internationalization and localization support and translate your code into it.